# PHP page won't produce output from php page with $_SERVER == "POST" method

Tags: php

I put together a code to get the output to show up on the same page as the php page but it won't show. What was done wrong? I am not sure why. I made sure this was run on the web browser to see if outcome will show, but it did not.

Here is source code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head></head>
    <body>  
    <?php
    // define variables and set to empty values
    $name = $email = $gender = $comment = $website = "";

    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        $name = test_input($_POST ["name"]);
        $email = test_input($_POST ["email"]);
        $website = test_input($_POST ["website"]);
        $comment = test_input($_POST ["comment"]);
        $gender = test_input($_POST ["gender"]);
    }
    function test_input($data) {
        $data = trim($data);
        $data = stripslashes($data);
        $data = htmlspecialchars($data);

        return $data;
    }
    ?>

    <h2>PHP Form Validation Example</h2>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
        Name: <input type="text" name="name"> <br>
        <br> E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"> <br>
        <br> Website: <input type="text" name="website"> <br>
        <br> Comment:
        <textarea name="comment" rows="5" cols="40"></textarea>
        <br>
        <br> Gender: <input type="radio" name="gender" value="female">Female <input
            type="radio" name="gender" value="male">Male <br>
        <br> <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>

    <?php
    echo "<h2>Your Input:</h2>";
    echo $name;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $email;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $website;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $comment;
    echo "<br>";
    echo $gender;
    ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the need to use `$_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"]`?

Comment: Have you tested after form submit ? Its working fine.

Comment: Well I tested in on my PC and its working fine.

Comment: I ran this using phpStorm. It's not showing the outcomes when I am running this on Chrome

Comment: Can you explain what you are doing and what you are expecting ? like I fill the inputs, I click on submit and so on...

Comment: @James please remove test_input(); and working fine.

Comment: do you have a webserver like apache2? it works on my machine too....

Comment: Just learning PHP now and I put together this a practice. I expect to see name and email I inputted at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I am running this on localhost. So maybe I should use GET method instead?

Comment: `POST` is a must unless you really need to use `GET` and it is working on me. Are you using `XAMPP`?